# fs readFile code in Node.js somehow broke

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, fs

I have a simple web application that I am using with Node.js and Express. This is my package structure:

[image]

The contents of my `questions.json` file are as follows:

```
[
  {
    "question": "What is your favorite color?",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "question": "How old are you?",
    "id": 2
  },
]
```

And `operations.json` contains this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const questions = 'public/questions.json';

class Operations{
  constructor() {
    fs.readFile(questions, (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      this.questions = JSON.parse(data);
    });
  }

  findID(id) {
    for (let key in this.questions) {
      if (this.questions[key].id == id) {
        console.log('found it!');
      }
    }
    console.log("can't find it!...");
  }
}

var test = new Operations();
test.findID(1);
```

This code used to work before but now for some odd reason, it is broken. The output of `test.findID(1);` Always returns `can't find it...` And I cannot figure out why. If I do a `console.log(this.questions)` outside of my constructor, it always prints `undefined`, but if I were to `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` inside the callback function of the `fs.readFile` it will display the contents of the file.

Comment: `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, I doubt the code would have never been working as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably test.findID(1) is being executed before the actual IO reading happens, so at that moment, questions is undefined.

Try using [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) instead of fs.readFile. This should be actually be fine, as you are still within the constructor of the object.

Comment: But isn't fs.readFileSync() blocking? On the index page of my application, I display the questions in an HTML list and I previously used fs.readFileSync(), but  sometimes when I would navigate to a different route and go back to the index, the page wouldn't load and show the crash screen until a few seconds later after doing a refresh

Comment: Yes, fs.readFileSync() waits until your text file has been read, which is what you want, because if not, that variable would be undefined. You could also move your logic inside the callback, but I wouldn't recommend that since you are still inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had another issue as well in my routing files, like for example index.js, I was sending it res.('index',  {questions: operation.question }; which was also causing things to not get loaded.